# Android Studio/IntelliJ tweening trouble using libgdx

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx, tween

I have encountered a problem trying to use the Universal Tweening Engine.  My IDE is Android Studio/IntelliJ.  So here is my issue.  I copied the tween-engine-api.jar and tween-engine-api-sources.jar into my IDE and added them both as libraries.  When I tried to use them in my source code, I get this error when I try to run it on my Android phone:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.rohit.zombiebird.com.rohit.TweenAccessors.ValueAccessor
        at com.rohit.zombiebird.com.rohit.GameWorld.GameRenderer.prepareTransition(GameRenderer.java:313)
        at com.rohit.zombiebird.com.rohit.GameWorld.GameRenderer.<init>(GameRenderer.java:81)
        at com.rohit.zombiebird.com.rohit.Screens.GameScreen.<init>(GameScreen.java:26)
        at com.rohit.zombiebird.Gameclass.create(Gameclass.java:17)
        at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:236)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1512)
        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

This has frustrated me for the past day and a half.  Here is a line of my source code:

```
    Tween.registerAccessor(Value.class, new ValueAccessor());
```

This is line 81 in the GameRenderer class.  I have searched for solutions, but I could only find solutions for Eclipse, not for IntelliJ.  Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated.